# Are there any surviving hymns from the Valdensian movement?

Tags: history, worship, music, medieval-church, waldensians

The Valdensians preached and celebrated the Lord's Supper in the native tongue of the people, not in Latin. However, every source I've read about their customs focus on what was **spoken**, while I also want to know what they **sang**.

Do we have any sources that describe their songs, when and how they were sung or indeed if they did sing during their worship services at all?

Of course this question is about the oldest era of the Valdensian movement, way before it merged with Calvinistic Protestantism.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I contacted the Valdensian Seminary in Rome and got this reply, from Lothar Vogel, professor of Church History:

> Dear Mr. Gunther,
>
> I thank you very much for your kind request and for your interest in
>   Waldensian history.
>
> I can tell you that there are no sources concerning medieval
>   Waldensian hymns or liturgies linked to Eucharistiv celebrations. At
>   the latest from 14th century on the liturgical pratise was factually
>   limited to confession, and the Waldensians participated at the
>   sacramental practice of the "great church" (baptism, eucharist).

The answer is, thus, "no".